# How to get Boost threads installed on Visual C++?

Tags: installation, boost-thread, visual-c++-2010

I'm new to multithreading and so, I wanted to start learning Boost threading. However, before I even start, I'd like to know how to get all the files working with Visual C++ 2010. As a beginner, it can be very frustrating having to deal with not just code related problems, but with a faulty installation. 
Tried to find it online, but couldn't come up with any good resource.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Comment: bare in mind most of boost threads have been added to the standard library in C++11. I don't know where VS2012 stands on the matter but I should imagine that VS2012 will support `std::thread` and friends very well.

Comment: The "Getting started" page of boost has [Information on how to download and install the libraries on Visual Studio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary).

Comment: Installing boost with VC++10 is actually reasonably painless *if* you follow the instructions on the boost page linked by Arne Metz above. I did it a few weeks ago, took some time to compile but afterwards it worked without having to fiddle around a lot.

Comment: I actually tried downloading the installer, and installing it but it still won't run. It can't locate the boost header file for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had done that this week for first time too. I wanted to link it statically and apparently the installer just copy the dlls (I have to confirm this). Surely there is a better way to do it, but what worked for me was download the whole set and run the bat file that generates the lib files.

After that is just a matter of setting up the additional include and lib directories on the project.